# como puedo enviar en un button un $evento mas un valor producto_item

Tags: javascript, html5, angular, ionic, ionic-framework

bueno tengo un botón que abre un popover y quiero pasarle un item pero no se como conseguirlo pues el botón ya lleva un evento no se si me explico muy bien, este es el código del button en el html:

```
<ion-buttons >
            <ion-button (click)="mostrarPop($event)">
              <ion-icon slot="start" ios="ellipsis-horizontal" md="ellipsis-vertical"></ion-icon>
            </ion-button>
          </ion-buttons>
```

y bueno como dentro del popover hay varios botones quiero que uno de ellos me realice la función que llama este otro botón que tengo en el html y quiero recuperar el item de este botón

```
<ion-button color="danger" size="small"  fill="clear"  (click)="del_product(product_item)">
             Eliminar
             <ion-icon slot="end" name="trash-outline"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
```

es decir quiero pasar el valor de producto_item con el botón del popover y después recuperar ese valor pero no se hacerlo y llevo dos días si alguien puede echarme un cable.

Comment: Puedes usar un BehaviorSubject  para crear un evento luego simplemente le pasas al evento un dato y lo recuperar desde donde sea necesario.
Para esto es mejor que crees un servicion de eventos.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject

Comment: Hola gracias de antetodo, no se si me sirve yo lo quiero para implementarlo aqui : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/488413/ion-popover-implementar-funci%c3%b3n-al-clickar